# HTTParty, Rails & Sinatra: Same (get) request, different response (behaviour)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, get, sinatra, httparty

I've written a `ruby gem` that uses `httparty` to make various `http requests`. It works from `irb` and in `rails` apps but I am getting a very weird behaviour when I try to use it in a `sinatra` one.

The `gem` looks like this

**gem:**

```
require "httparty"
class SomeAPI::Client
 def initizialize(some_params)
   @api_params = some_params
 end

 def login
   login_response = HTTParty.get(@api_params[:login_url])
   puts "Login Result: #{login_response}"
 end
end
```

and when I try to login from `irb` everything is fine.

Then I include it on my `rails app gemfile` (`gem "SomeAPI", :path => "~/dev/SomeAPI"`), setup an action in a controller and trying to login from `0:0:0:0:3000/someapi?api_params=my_params` works fine.

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def someapi
    client = SomeAPI::Client.new(params[:api_params])
    client.login
  end
end
```

Finally, I try to do the same thing from my `sinatra app`: I include it in the `gemfile` and I try to make the request from `0:0:0:0:9292/someapi/:my_params`. However, although, the `new` works fine (`client` becomes a `SomeAPI` object with all the attributes initizialized properly), the `login` gives me a `You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.` error message; as if I am trying to access a different resource (or as if login itself needs me to be authenticated beforehands to succeed). Here is the code:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
  get "/someapi/:my_params" do
    client = SomeAPI::Client.new
    client.login
  end
end
```

I tried running the sinatra app from port 3000 (the same as the rails' default) but nothing changed.

Any ideas or leads on where to look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding the below code to the `login` method:

```
params =
  {
    :headers => { "Content-Type" => "application/xml", "Accept" => "application/xml"},
    :basic_auth => { :username => "some_username", :password => "some_password" }
  }
```

(and of course changing the `request` to `HTTParty.get(@api_params[:login_url], params)`)